# Access elements in ul list

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have the following list hierarchy:

```
<ul id="ulid">
    <li><a><div class="mydiv">content</div></a></li>
    <li><a><div class="mydiv">content</div></a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I want to add some css rules to the div and this is what i've tried so far:

```
var myul = document.getElementById("ulid");
var myli = myul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0; i < myli.length; i++) {
    //myli[i].parentNode.style.display = "none"; // that works
    var links = myli[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var ii = 0; ii < links.length; ii++) {
        links[ii].parentNode.style.display = "none"; // doesnt work
    }
}
```

I can hide the `li` items but cant do the same for `a` So i cant reach the div. What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT: `getElementsByClassName` seems not working in greasemonkey scripts as it simply works in Emmanuel N's fiddle.

Comment: How about that: `var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv")`?

Comment: Worth noting that a `div` tag inside an `a` tag is invalid markup.  If you're looking for a generic inline container user `span`.

Comment: Why are you always using `parentNode`? And what would be wrong with just doing `myul.getElementsByTagName("div")` (or `"a"`, not sure which you actually want)?

Comment: Seems like it works fine, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C56DM/) fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work. Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C56DM/) Fiddle

```
  var myul = document.getElementById("ulid");
  var myli = myul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for(var i = 0; i < myli.length; i++) 
  {
       var links = myli[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
       for(var ii = 0; ii < links.length; ii++) 
       {
              links[ii].parentNode.style.display = "none";
       }
  }
```

Comment: I'm writing a greasemonkey script. May be that's the reason?

Comment: Probably that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually does work, but I don't think it does what you're intending it to do. The last line: links[ii].parentNode.style.display = "none"  will actually hide the parent node of the a tag (i.e. the li) tag, rather than the div. parentNode will go one level UP, not down.

Instead of trying to get myli[i].getElementsByTagName("a") and then working down to the div, why not myli[i].getElementsByTagName("div"), and then simply do:

```
var myul = document.getElementById("ulid");
var myli = myul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0; i < myli.length; i++) {
    //myli[i].parentNode.style.display = "none"; // that works
    var links = myli[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var ii = 0; ii < links.length; ii++) {
        links[ii].style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
```

Of course, there are many more efficient ways to do it. You already have classnames on the divs, so

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv");
```

would work just as well.

Or, if you use jQuery, you can do the same thing without having to iterate explicitly:

```
$("div.mydiv").css(etc.); // style this however you want
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed to using jQuery, the following would hide your divs for you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myDivs = $('div.mydiv');
    for(var eachDiv in myDivs) {
        $(eachDiv).hide();
    }   
 });
```